# page in background while trying to open new page using code behind

Tags: c#, javascript

I am trying to open a new page from the code. For this I used the following code on button click event

```
string pageURL = UIConstants.Url.PrintUserBRCs + "?" + UIConstants.ReportType + "=" + UIConstants.DetailReport;

string script = string.Format("window.open('{0}', null, 'height=600, width=800, status=yes, location=yes, menubar=yes, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, status=yes, toolbar=yes, titlebar=yes')", pageURL);

Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "LaunchTemplate", script, true);
```

The new page is opening properly but it has the issue that the new page goes in the background while the old page appears at top.

I need to show the new page opened at top of previous page.
How can I do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `focus()` like this:

```
string script = string.Format("var newWindow = window.open('{0}', null, 'height=600, width=800, status=yes, location=yes, menubar=yes, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, status=yes, toolbar=yes, titlebar=yes');"
                                      + " newWindow.focus();", pageURL);
```